# How to partition a dataset based on multiple metadata attributes in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

If we have a dataset with the following metadata: `Age`, `Gender`, `PersonId`.

Is there a Python library that can partition the dataset into a training, development and test partitions based on all three metadata attributes mentioned above as well as the label `c`?

Comment: I guess you are mixing up things. Do you want to classify samples based on age, gender and label c( unknown) or just divide the samples into test and training datasets?

Comment: The latter, with one addition that this divide is not solely based on the label. I would like for the partitions to be balanced in terms of age and gender as well. The dataset contains other attributes, hence the `etc`

Comment: Do you still need time to accept the answer?!

Answer (score 2):

You should not partition a dataset based on the ***independent*** variables (a.k.a features)... Why?

Simply, because you will end up with an almost guaranteed ***unbalanced*** distribution.

In other words, suppose that the attribute `age` in your dataset ranges between 20 to 60, now if you split them according to `age` you will possibly end up having young people in your training set, and the old ones in your test set or vice versa..etc.

In this case your model will not train properly, and you will end up over-fitting / under-fitting your model!

---

The proper way to split them should be based on the ***dependent*** variable (a.k.a response, class or `y` variable).

Now suppose that your dataset contains only two classes: `Survived`, `Unsurvived`, now we should seek to ensure that each fold (i.e. training, development and test sets) is representative of all strata of the data.  That is to ensure each of the above-mentioned classes is (approximately) equally represented across each test fold.... Why?

To let your model gets the best possible training, because it doesn't make sense that you teach your model about one class (say for example `Survived`) more than the other. We want it to learn about all equally and that's why we want **all sets** to have from **all classes** as much as possible.

---

[StratifiedShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) does exactly what I mentioned (in case you don't mind using [Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html)).

Here is a simple example to start with:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```